# Derived class serialization - 'unregistered class' exception

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Trying to get boost serialization to work. The main idea is to have a base class that contains a few members and some derived classes, each derived class has it's own private members alongside with the base class members.

This is a minimal version of what I'm trying to do:

```
class base {
    public:
        virtual void print() = 0;
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned) {}
}

class derived20 : public base {
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned) {
            boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this);
            ar & var20;
        }
        
        int var20 = 20;
        
    public:
        void print() override { std::cout << var20 << std::endl; }
}

class derived40 : public base {
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned) {
            boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this);
            ar & var40;
        }
        
        int var40 = 40;
        
    public:
        void print() override { std::cout << var40 << std::endl; }
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(derived20)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(derived40)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(base)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ss);
    auto d20 = new derived20();
    ar << d20;
    
    // prints:
    // 22 serialization:archive 15 0 1 0
    // 0 20
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    
    boost::archive::text_iarchive iar(ss);
    base *b;
    iar >> b;
    b->print(); // Should print "20"
}
```

I'm getting an `archive_exception: unregistered class` error.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) says this about your exception **-** An attempt has been made to serialize a polymorphic class through a pointer without either registering it or associating it with an export key. This can also occur when using a new archive whose class name has not been added to the system with the BOOST_ARCHIVE_CUSTOM_ARCHIVE_TYPES macro.

Comment: [This](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is also relevant

Comment: @john but this is exactly what `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` does, no?

Comment: Sorry I missed that code (I didn't scroll down)

Comment: Slightly outside of my experience, but reading documentation I think you want `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID`. It seems `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` is about tracking not about registering. Worth a try anyway,

Comment: @john yes, I've tried that - no change, `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` is just a wrapper to `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID`

Comment: I would try not reusing the same stringstream for input and output. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Most of these were red herrings (except maybe the fact that the oarchvie should be closed/completed before attempting to deserialize from the underlying stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one rare occasion where `auto` might hurt:

```
auto d20 = new derived20();
ar << d20;
```

Contrast with:

```
base *b;
iar >> b;
```

Note how `d20` is `derived20*`, not `base*`. So you're invoking Undefined Behaviour by attempting to deserialize a type from an archive that contains another type.

Simply changing that:

```
base* d20 = new derived20();
```

Fixes everything:

> Also noticed that you forgot to actually *serialize* the base object.

**[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7701ef345e47b4e)**

```
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class base {
    public:
        virtual void print() = 0;
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & /*unused*/, unsigned /*unused*/) {}
};

class derived20 : public base {
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned /*unused*/) {
            ar & boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this)
               & var20;
        }
        
        int var20 = 20;
        
    public:
        void print() override { std::cout << var20 << std::endl; }
};

class derived40 : public base {
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned /*unused*/) {
            ar & boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this)
               & var40;
        }
        
        int var40 = 40;
        
    public:
        void print() override { std::cout << var40 << std::endl; }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(derived20)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(derived40)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(base)

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ss);
        base* d20 = new derived20();
        ar << d20;
    }
    
    // prints:
    // 22 serialization:archive 15 0 1 0
    // 0 20
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    
    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive iar(ss);
        base *b = nullptr;
        iar >> b;
        b->print(); // Should print "20"
    }
}
```

Prints

```
22 serialization::archive 17 0 9 derived20 1 0
0 20

20
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I wasted so much time on this!

Comment: Oh - I've been there. It sucks, but part of the game. Cheers!